# How do I resolve CORS in Apache Ignite?

Tags: java, cors, ignite

I have an Apache Ignite server running in a basic Java application. The Ignite REST api is exposed on a certain port. When I hit it from the browser, it is returning the desired response. However, from an Angular app, I am getting CORS error.

Is there any solution to this? Note that this application runs Ignite REST api (the one which is giving the CORS). How do I allow cross-origins inside the Ignite REST api?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say you can configure it via Jetty ~ https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#section-sample-jetty-xml-configuration. See also https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html

Comment: But, how do I use the ConnecctorConfiguration? I am running the Ignite node with a basic config file and, before that, I am setting the REST port for Jetty (IGNITE_JETTY_PORT) by System.setProperty

Comment: How do I pass the ConnectorConfiguration to the Ignite instance? @Phil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't heard about the right way to achieve that. 
`CORS` filtration in Jetty is [configurable](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html) through `Servlet` filtration API. This functionality is provided by [ServletHandler](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHandler.html). It seems that `Ignite` utilizes its own [Handler](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/rest-http/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/rest/protocols/http/jetty/GridJettyRestHandler.java) to serve `HTTP` requests. As far as I understand it doesn't support cross-domain requests.

In general I don't think that it's good idea to direct `HTTP` request to an `Ignite` cluster from a browser. It doesn't look absolutely secure and architecturally correct. I'd prefer to have separate back-end application which should be responsible for processing of your `Angular` application load.

Comment: Is there any way to provide CORS support in Ignite? For example, passing the CORS allowance in the configurations for the Ignite node.

Comment: I agree. Direct HTTP request is not a good approach at all. And, technically, I do not think it is possible to resolve CORS in this case, using the handler of Ignite.